# How to use JQPlot with Angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I want to use jqplot with angular 2. I have done the following things in Component.

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
declare var jQuery: any;
declare var jqplot: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './app/home/home.component.html'

 })

export class HomeComponent {


 constructor(public ele: ElementRef) {}

   ngAfterViewInit() {

    console.log(this.ele.nativeElement.children[0]);
    var arr = [[11, 123, 1236, "Acura"], [45, 92, 1067, "Alfa Romeo"],
        [24, 104, 1176, "AM General"], [50, 23, 610, "Aston Martin Lagonda"],
        [18, 17, 539, "Audi"], [7, 89, 864, "BMW"], [2, 13, 1026, "Bugatti"]];


    console.log(jqplot)
    // jQuery.jqplot(this.ele.nativeElement.children[0], [arr], {
    //     title: 'Transparent Bubbles',
    //     seriesDefaults: {
    //         renderer: jQuery.jqplot.BubbleRenderer,
    //         rendererOptions: {
    //             bubbleAlpha: 0.6,
    //             highlightAlpha: 0.8
    //         },
    //         shadow: true,
    //         shadowAlpha: 0.05
    //     }
    // });
  }
}
```

In console 'jQuery.jqplot' is null. And this is view

```
   <div id ="mychart" #ch></div>
```

When I run the application this error appears in console.

```
  Error: Permission denied to access property "rejection"
```

What is this error all about. Guide me how can I use jqPlot in angular 2. I have include jquery and jqplot files in index.html